# "Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key" when running sess.run()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

> TypeError: Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.

... is being displayed when I run the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
print(tf.__version__)

seed_num=1
data_path = 'Caltech-256/'
batch_size = 80  # the number of images to load per iteration
target_size=(64,64) # pixel size of each image
num_pixels_and_channels = (64,64,3) # pixels and channels 
input_shape = (1,64,64,3) 
layer = 1
feature = 0

val_data_gen_aug_rotate = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
                                                               validation_split=0.1)


val_img = val_data_gen_aug_rotate.flow_from_directory(data_path, 
                                           subset='validation',
                                           color_mode='rgb',
                                           target_size=target_size,
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           class_mode='categorical',
                                           seed=seed_num)

sample_imgs_val, sample_labels_val = next(val_img)

model = load_model("Models/ex_13_epoch_4_3563_336.h5")


sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
input_layer = model.layers[0].input
output_layer = model.layers[layer].output

outputs = sess.run(output_layer, feed_dict = {input_layer : sample_imgs_val})
```

The issue is with the code `outputs = sess.run(output_layer, feed_dict = {input_layer : sample_imgs_val})`. What is causing the error and how can it be fixed?

I'm using tensorflow version 2.1.0 on a CPU via a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: You are trying to use a session from TensorFlow 1.x, which is for graph mode, in TensorFlow 2.x, which works in eager mode by default. The error is complaining specifically about trying to use a tensor as a dict key, but in general you cannot use sessions in eager mode. Have a look at the [changes introduced by TensorFlow 2.x](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2) and [tips to migrate your code from TensorFlow 1.x](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2).

Comment: Thanks. That explains whats going wrong. I'm not yet clear on what I need to do to fix it though so help there would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to version.

You are trying to use Tensorflow 1.x, which works in graph mode whereas TensorFlow 2.x works in eager mode.

Comment: Thanks. That explains whats going wrong. I'm not yet clear on what I need to do to fix it though so help there would be appreciated.